# How can I visualize the mean value on a jitter plot using altair?

Tags: python, altair

> I need to get the mean value of each continent and plot it on the jitter chart
> Just found this awesome library called altair and i want to plot a jitter chart like the one i found below, but I need to get the mean value of each continent and plot it on the jitter chart.
>
> to start i import the two needed libraries

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
```

> get the data from the source

```
data_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/resbaz/r-novice-gapminder files/master/data/gapminder-FiveYearData.csv'
```

> read the csv file

```
gapminder = pd.read_csv(data_url)
```

> start plotting at altair

```
stripplot =  alt.Chart(gapminder).mark_circle(size=14).encode(
    x=alt.X(
        'jitter:Q',
        title=None,
        axis=alt.Axis(values=[0], ticks=True, grid=False, labels=False),
        scale=alt.Scale(),
    ),
    y=alt.Y('lifeExp:Q',
           scale=alt.Scale(
            domain=(20,90))),
    color=alt.Color('continent:N', legend=None),
    column=alt.Column(
        'continent:N',
        header=alt.Header(
            labelFontSize=16,
            labelAngle=0,
            titleOrient='top',
            labelOrient='bottom',
            labelAlign='center',
            labelPadding=25,
        ),
    ),
).transform_calculate(
    # Generate Gaussian jitter with a Box-Muller transform
    jitter='sqrt(-2*log(random()))*cos(2*PI*random())'
).configure_facet(
    spacing=0
).configure_view(
    stroke=None
).configure_axis(
    labelFontSize=16,
    titleFontSize=16
).properties(height=400, width=100)
stripplot
```

> the code runs great but I neet to display also the mean values of each continent

Answer (score 1):

Add the mean before faceting, as layering can not happen after the faceted table has been made. Read more at https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1158 by jakevdp

```
stripplot =  alt.Chart(df, width=40).mark_point(size=8).encode(
    x=alt.X(
    'jitter:Q',
    title=None,
    axis=alt.Axis(values=[0], ticks=True, grid=False, labels=False),
    scale=alt.Scale(),
),
    y=alt.Y('lifeExp:Q'),
    color=alt.Color('continent:N', legend=None),
).transform_calculate(
# Generate Gaussian jitter with a Box-Muller transform
jitter='sqrt(-2*log(random()))*cos(2*PI*random())'
)
meanplot=alt.Chart(df, width=40).mark_tick(size=20).encode(
    y=alt.Y('mean(lifeExp):Q'),
    color=alt.Color('continent:N', legend=None),
)
fullplot=(meanplot+stripplot).facet(
    column=alt.Column(
        'continent:N',
        header=alt.Header(
            labelAngle=-90,
            titleOrient='top',
            labelOrient='bottom',
            labelAlign='right',
            labelPadding=3,
    ),

),
).configure_facet(
spacing=0
).configure_view(
stroke=None
)
fullplot
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using numpy library, it does that :

```
import numpy as np

data = [15,50,30,40]
Print("Mean:",np.mean(data))
```

Output :

```
('mean:', 33.75)
```